# Casting in Jython 2.5.3

Tags: casting, apache-pig, jython, ctypes

There is a Python function, that runs in CPython 2.5.3 but crashes in Jython 2.5.3 .
It is part of a user defined function in Apache Pig, which uses Jython 2.5.3 so i cannot change it.

The input is a array of singed bytes, but in fact that are unsigned bytes, so i need to cast it.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import array
import ctypes

assert isinstance(input, array.array), 'unexpected input parameter'
assert input.typecode == 'b', 'unexpected input type'

buffer = StringIO()
for byte in input:
    s_byte = ctypes.c_byte(byte)
    s_byte_p = ctypes.pointer(s_byte)
    u_byte = ctypes.cast(s_byte_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)).contents.value
    buffer.write(chr(u_byte))
buffer.seek(0)
output = buffer.getvalue()

assert isinstance(output, str)
```

The error is:

```
s_byte = ctypes.cast(u_byte_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte)).contents.value
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cast'
```

I guess the ctypes.cast functions is not implemeted in Jython 2.5.3 . Is there a workaround for that issue?

Thanks,
Steffen

Comment: That code can probable be reimplemented using `struct.unpack` and `struct.pack`, see [struct module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, that is quite ugly but works without additional dependecies.
It uses the bit representation of usinged und signed bytes (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweierkomplement).

```
import array

assert isinstance(input, array.array), 'unexpected input parameter'
assert input.typecode == 'b', 'unexpected input type'

output = array.array('b', [])

for byte in input:

    if byte > 127:
        byte = byte & 127
        byte = -128 + byte

    output.append(byte)
```